# having flutter Just audio player plugin having a source error

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

I'm creating this music player and I want to play audio in my playlist I'm using on_audio_query plugins to query all the audios specifically in my playlist folder that I created, and I'm using just_audio plugin as my player. but the problem is every time I try to play the songs it returns me an error saying source error

```
FutureBuilder<List<SongModel>>(
          future: _audioQuery.queryAudiosFrom(
              AudiosFromType.PLAYLIST, widget.playlistpath,
              ignoreCase: true),
          builder: (context, item) {
            if (item.data == null) {
              return const Text("Searching for audio");
            }
            if (item.data!.isEmpty) {
              return const Text("No music Audio found");
            }
            return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: item.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(item.data![index].title),
                    onTap: () async {
                      try {
                        debugPrint("${item.data![index].uri}");
                        await _player.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(
                            Uri.parse(item.data![index].uri!)));
                        // await _player.setAudioSource(
                        //     createPlaylist(item.data!),
                        //     initialIndex: index);
                        await _player.play();
                      } catch (e) {
                        debugPrint("$e");
                      }
                    },
                  );
                });
          }),
```

> I/flutter (18513): (0) Source error

Comment: do you still need an answer

Comment: @Gwhyyy just put your answer so the flutter community who has the same problem will find this question. it would be a big help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro I'm also facing this issue. I didn't got any solution. So what I did was, I just stored current song map item in a varialbe and just used that map item to play song in just_audio:

```
void playSong() {

Map map = widget.songModel.getMap;

try{
  setState(() {
    isPlaying = true;
    indexno = widget.indexno;
    songId = widget.songModel.id;
    songName = widget.songModel.displayNameWOExt;
    artistName = widget.songModel.artist!;
  });

  audioPlayer.setAudioSource(
    AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(map['_data']))
  );

  audioPlayer.play();

} on Exception {
  log("cannot parse audio");
}}
```

Here **map['_data']** will return exact location of audio.

eg:- "***/storage/6804-D450/music/ma music/music.mp3***".

You can also print the map variable to see other fields.